# get/read raw post data from php://input using CURL and not using file_get_contents

Tags: php, curl, http-post, file-get-contents

My server guys disabled all socket functions and after requesting them they enabled CURL and i am negotiating with them for other functions.

Meanwhile in one of my code i want to read raw post data from **php://input**

I was using **file_get_contents("php://input")** to get raw post data but with only curl enabled in my server i could not do that.

So i want to know how to read raw posted data using curl.

Give your thoughts please.

Comment: curl is used to communicate with remote servers (from the php script's point of view), it's not used for reading streams of the php script/process itself.

Comment: Can you not just use the standard super global arrays?

Comment: @Ing from php documentation: php://input is a read-only stream that allows you to read raw data from the request body. In the case of POST requests, it is preferable to use php://input instead of $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Yes, but I mean $_POST not $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA

Comment: @Ing - when we do a raw post there will not be any key value pairs... no query strings... just the data will be posted like am xml content or json... this is how all the sites do a raw post ... and there is difference between http_post and http_raw_post... so hope i have made it clear

Comment: Well tbh, you confused me.... so went away and had a play with this, comparing $_POST to php://input. And they basically seem to store the same data in different formats (array Vs query string). Can you give me an example where this is not the case?

Comment: yes. i will give you an example. i will do it on monday as i am in my farm house now for the weekend. and will also delete this comment cause this will not be useful for others. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to my another question related to this i got an alternate. and it worked.

[what are the alternatives for php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA when file_get_contents and always_populate_raw_post_data are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907896/what-are-the-alternatives-for-php-input-and-http-raw-post-data-when-file-get)

since file_get_contents was disabled and curl was the only way for communication i was trying to use wrappers in curl like php;//input which i think no possible yet i got this alternate.

so the link is an alternate for file_get_contents("php://input");