# what are the alternatives for php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA when file_get_contents and always_populate_raw_post_data are disabled

Tags: http, file-get-contents, php-ini

My hosting comp has disabled all the socket functionality except curl. They are so irresponsible on my questions for enabling it. i can think of another hosting yet i want to know the following.

I have asked a question related to this and this is a continuation yet another question.

I am unable to use file_get_contents('php://input') and always_populate_raw_post_data is disabled in php.ini so i cannot use $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

So what is or are the alternatives to get a raw post data.

For example i have setup notifications callback url with facebook. so when ever there is an event then facebook will post information to my site's specific url.

so i need to read the raw post data from facebook and according to the above description i want to know the alternatives for php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.

**is it possible to read total content when some body posts to my site including the header so that i can strip off the header part and can use the body of the post?**

yeah... we can get the complete contents when some body posts any content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `file_get_contents()` is disabled you can use the great functionality of [PEAR::PHP_Compat](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat). It consists of an replacement for `file_get_contents()`.

Simply [download the latest package](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_Compat/download), extract it and use it like this:

```
require_once '/path/to/PHP_Compat-1.6.0a3/Compat/Function/file_get_contents.php';

$content = php_compat_file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

Comment: hallelujah, eeswaraa... that worked... haha... semma. thank you for the information.

Comment: The PEAR package checks for all possible ways to achieve the goal. There are a lot of other functions which are very helpful if something is restricted or if you use an old version of PHP.