# php - How to enable php://input stream wrapper for curl

Tags: php, libcurl

I was trying to do the following

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"php://input" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
echo curl_error($ch);
echo $result;
```

to get raw post data using curl because my hosting com disabled all socket functions except curl so i cannot do file_get_contents("php://input");

i get an error like

> Protocol php not supported or disabled in libcurl1

what shall i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://www.php.net/manual/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php) instead of "php://input". For details see the php://input section at http://php.net/manual/wrappers.php.php

Other solution: [what are the alternatives for php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA when file_get_contents and always_populate_raw_post_data are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907896/what-are-the-alternatives-for-php-input-and-http-raw-post-data-when-file-get/10320453#10320453)

Comment: the hosting company has disabled the respective setting in php.ini

Comment: Sounds like your hosting company can't support your requirements

Answer (score 1):

you don't need socket functions to access `php://input`, it is accessed by standard `fopen`, and if your hosting company blocks `fopen`  then you should think about changing provider not, the code.