# php curl method does not get php://input

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

[updated]
[solved :D]
I am coding a telegram bot.
My host does not allow me to use `file_get_contents();` method !
I want to do file_get_contents("php://input"); by cURL method !
And also this code does not work ! :

```
$c = curl_init('php://input');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);


$html = curl_exec($c);

if (curl_error($c))
    die(curl_error($c));


$status = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($c);
```

What should i do ?

[how to solve] :

thanks to all ! :D

here is how i solved my problem :

[what are the alternatives for php://input and $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA when file_get_contents and always_populate_raw_post_data are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907896/what-are-the-alternatives-for-php-input-and-http-raw-post-data-when-file-get)

Comment: I'd suggest you move to a less restrictive host! But if you want to persist with this method, please post the input to / output of your script, and what you expect each to be.

Comment: thanks to all ! :D this helped me : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907896/what-are-the-alternatives-for-php-input-and-http-raw-post-data-when-file-get